# PHP:MYSQL array to JSON stop duplicating?

Tags: php, mysql, json

So whenever I download data from my mysql database, and convert to a JSON array via PHP then display it, I get duplicated values.

I do understand why this is so, but is there any way to remove the numeric duplicates?:/

```
{"id":"1","0":"1","userId":"23","1":"23","message":"HELLO","2":HELLO"},
{"id":"2","0":"2","userId":"53","1":"53","message":"WOW","2":WOW"}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the default "both" fetch option. You need to specify associative only. Is it PDO or mysqli?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Open a manual for database api you use and find answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDO use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` flag after query execute

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT col FROM table");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

And for mysql_* functions:

```
$query = "SELECT col FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $row;
}
json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've asked, to remove it:
Loop through it, if key is numeric delete.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$var){ 
    if(is_numeric($key)){ 
        delete $array[$key]; 
    } 
}
```